# Batch - search a TXT file (show everything after a certain line?)

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, search, text-files

I'm trying to isolate a part of a text file with a FOR loop.

Example:
C:\temp.txt contains the following lines:
1
2
3
phrase abc
4
5
phrase xyz
6
7
8
9
10

I want the loop to echo every line after "phrase xyz", but i can't find a way.
To be clear, the result i need in this example would be:
6
7
8
9
10

I tried something like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=phrase xyz" %%A IN (C:\temp.txt) DO ECHO %%B
```

but it doesn't seem possible to use anything other than ONE word as the "DELIMS" value and it also doesn't work because the other lines don't contain the phrase so I'm confused at how to tackle this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"phrase xyz" C:\temp.txt') do more +%%a C:\temp.txt`

Comment: Works very nice thank you, can you please explain the "do more +%%a" part? I understand the findstr /n part but not this one.

Comment: If you read the `more /?` [help screen](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html), you'll realize that the `+n` option "Start displaying the first file at line n" instead of at the first line...

Comment: Ah, very good, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong approach. The `delims` clause species a *set of characters* that will be used as token-delimiters within a line.

Your "show all lines after a particular string" problem may be solved as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "output="
(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (inputfilename) do (
 if defined output echo %%a
 if "%%a"=="phrase xyz" set "output=Y"
)
)>outputfilename
```

This first sets `output` to *empty* then for each line of the input file (`delims=` turns delimiters off so that the entire line is delivered to `%%a`), if `output` is defined, display the line read.Then check whether it is **exactly** `phrase xyz` and if so, set `output` to `Y`

Consequently, when the target string is found, the flag `output` is set (the value to which it is set is irrelevant - it just needs to be not-*empty*) and lines appearing thereafter are output.

Normally, `echo` will send the output to the screen, but if the entire `for` statement is surrounded by a pair of parentheses, the output can be redirected easily to a file. - this is the purpose of the lone `(` before the `for` and the `)>filename` after.

If you want to make a case-insensitive comparison, use `if /i` in place of `if`.

There are other options, depending on your real purpose.

Comment: Perfect answer, the code is clear, well explained and I now learned a nice method of achieving this which will be used many times in the future. THANK YOU so much for everything, much appreciated. Implemented in the real situation it works very well!